How to send traces to Elastic Cloud APM using OpenTelemetry OTLP (without using the Collector) in nodejs
I am trying to send distributed traces to Elastic Cloud APM and because I want to be able to send traces originating from multiple services, I cannot use elastic-apm-node as it only supports only a single service. The documentation says you can use OTLP directly or via the OTLP Collector. I have a simple implementation below that should work but it doesn't. Any ideas before I have to setup an additional layer with the OTLP Collector so see if that will work?
const { NodeTracerProvider } = require('@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node');
const { OTLPTraceExporter } = require('@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-http');
const { SimpleSpanProcessor, ConsoleSpanExporter } = require('@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base');
const { Resource } = require('@opentelemetry/resources');
const { trace, context } = require('@opentelemetry/api');

// Configure resource with service metadata
const resource = new Resource({
  'service.name': 'your-service-name',
  'service.version': '1.0.0',
  'deployment.environment': 'test',
});

// Initialize tracer provider with the resource
const provider = new NodeTracerProvider({ resource });

// Configure OTLP Exporter
const otlpExporter = new OTLPTraceExporter({
  url: 'https://XXXxxxxxx.apm.europe-west3.gcp.cloud.es.io:443/v1/traces',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer XXXXXXxxxxx',
  },
});

// Add span processors
provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(new ConsoleSpanExporter())); // Debug locally
provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(otlpExporter));
provider.register();

// Obtain a tracer
const tracer = trace.getTracer('your-service-name');

// Create a parent span
const parentSpan = tracer.startSpan('parent-operation', { kind: 1 }); // SERVER
const parentContext = trace.setSpan(context.active(), parentSpan);

// Use the parent context to start a child span
context.with(parentContext, () => {
  const childSpan = tracer.startSpan('child-operation', { kind: 2 }); // CLIENT
  childSpan.end(); // End the child span
});

parentSpan.end(); // End the parent span

